# How to split variable by colon in Batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am using batch for extracting information from `adb devices -l`, this command shows messages like this:

```
123456789012345    device product:abc model:ABC device:abc transport_id:7
```

I would like to get transport_id **7** from this string `transport_id:7`, so I try to split messages by space at first, and it works fine. But while trying to **split by colon**, I got an error said **The system cannot find the file transport_id:7**. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code.

```
@ECHO off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%a in ('adb.exe devices -l') do (
    if "%%b" == "device" ( 
        ECHO Serial Number : %%a
        ECHO Transport Id  : %%f
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ( %%f ) Do @Echo %%A
        call test.bat %%A
    )
)
PAUSE
```

Output and error:

```
Serial Number : 123456789012345
Transport Id  : transport_id:7
The system cannot find the file transport_id:7.
```

What does this error message **The system cannot find the file transport_id:7** means ?

Comment: Remark: DOS is case insensitive, so using both `%%a` and `%%A` is strange. For the problem try: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ("%%f") Do @Echo %%A`.

Comment: @harrymc but I still don't know why adding double quotes to `%%f` can fix this problem, would you mind explaining more ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct formulation for solving the problem is:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ("%%f") Do @Echo %%A
```

Without the double-quotes around the `%%f`, it is taken as a file-name.
The double-quotes cause it to be treated as a string.